# The difference in meaning between 俺 and 我

Tags: meaning, difference

I stumble upon the word '俺' when my mom was talking to someone from a different region of China but the dialect was still the same. 俺 and 我 both mean the same thing right?

Comment: They mean the same, I or me.  俺 is a local dialect prevalent in the Shandong Province.

Answer (score 1):

俺----- ǎn, means "I, we (俺们)", is a personal pronoun  in Northern dialect.

Comment: Japanese use 俺/ore/ :  'me'  too

Answer (score 0):

I always think of the Monkey King when I hear 俺。

孙悟空为什么称自己为俺老孙?
Why does the Monkey King call himself I, Old Sun (俺老孙）?

俺和我为同义词，
俺 and 我 are the same meaning,
还有孙悟空姓孙，
also 孙悟空's surname is 孙,
再加上他岁数比较大，
add to that he is relatively old,
几百多岁，
several hundred years,
看到妖精自然而然称自己为俺老孙！
(when) he sees an evil spirit he automatically calls himself I, Old Sun (俺老孙）